# .NET application deployment Error in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

[image]When I am trying to deploy a .net application in the IIS Server I am getting an error as Configuration settings do not match. Please help me with this.

Comment: post the screenshot

Comment: share your web.confing file along with the error screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is specifically to do with 'client impersonation'. I had the error on one machine but not on another. By comparing settings I worked out the difference.

Start IIS Manager. Select the server in the left pane and double-click 'Authentication' under the IIS group in the central pane. Select ASP.NET Impersonation and select 'Disable' at the top of the right pane.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this in Web.Config

```
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
```